# Wget file format

Tags: pdf, wget

I have to download all site content and then parse the downloaded folder for "*.pdf" files. I am downloading site using `wget -r --no-parent http://www.example.com/` But the problem is that sometimes link looks this

```
http://www.foodmanufuture.eu/dpubs?f=K20
```

and the dowloaded pdf is downloaded with name "dpubs?f=K20" and file format is not specified, it does not look like this "dpubs?f=K20.pdf", is there a way to check how many pdf files I have in this folder?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `--content-disposition` flag? From the man page:

> If this is set to on, experimental (not fully-functional) support for "Content-Disposition" headers is enabled. This can currently result in extra round-trips to the server for a "HEAD" request, and is known to suffer from a few bugs, which is why it is not currently enabled by default. **This option is useful for some file-downloading CGI programs that use "Content-Disposition" headers to describe what the name of a downloaded file should be**.

So it tries to ask the server for a filename. I tried it for the URL you gave and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the command

```
file filename
```

Like this:

```
file pdfurl-guide
pdfurl-guide: PDF document, version 1.5
```

You could use:

```
file *
```

To know exactly which files in your folder are pdf files